# Inverses without identity possible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $S$ is a nonempty set on which is defined a binary operation $*$ such that for all $x$, there exists a unique $y$, such that for all $z$, $x*yz=xy*z=y*xz=yx*z=z*xy=zx*y=x*zy=xz*y=y*zx=yz*x=z*yx=zy*x=z$, then does there exist an identity element in S, or even a left or right identity?

Comment: Are all those equal to $z$?

Comment: What is $yz$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $xy*z$ means $(x*y)*z$ and is just a notational convinience.

Two of the stated equalities say that $xy*z = z*xy = z$, from which $xy$ is (both left and right) identity, just by definition. A usual proof that *the* identity is unique holds: take $x'$ and $y'$, then $xy = xy*x'y' = x'y'$.

Comment: Uh, how silly of me. I am sorry for not noticing that.